# 同じPythonのソース（BS4でスクレイピング）でGoogleColaboratoryとJupyternotebookで実行結果が異なるのを解消したい

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, beautifulsoup, python-requests

以下のソースで検索結果に表示されるaタグの中の[data-jk]属性情報を取得しています。Jupyter Notebookで実行すると、画面で確認した状態である検索結果15件と同じ「15」という結果になりますが、Google Colaboratoryで実行すると「2」という結果になります。

Google Colaboratoryでも、画面に表示された状態の検索結果表示件数の情報を取得したいので対処方法を教えていただけますでしょうか。

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = "https://jp.indeed.com/%E6%B1%82%E4%BA%BA?q=feedid%3A255158+company%3A%22%E6%A0%AA%E5%BC%8F%E4%BC%9A%E7%A4%BEJD%22&filter=0"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
alllist = []
for elem in soup.select('a'):
    data_jk = elem.get('data-jk')
    alllist.append(data_jk)
    clean_alllist = list(filter(None, alllist))
len(clean_alllist)
```

Google Colaboratoryでこれまでに試したことは以下の通りです。いずれも事象解消に至りませんでした。

- Python（3.7.13）、BeautifulSoup4（4.9.1）、requests（2.24.0）のバージョンをそろえる。
- UserAgentを実際に自分の環境のもので指定してアクセスする。
- [requestsで取得できないWebページをスクレイピングする方法](https://gammasoft.jp/blog/how-to-download-web-page-created-javascript/) を参考にrequests-htmlを使用する。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 違いを調べるには, requests BeautifulSoup のどっちが影響してるかを調べるとよいかも。ローカルの `r.content` をファイルへ書き込み, colabに upload ＆ 読み込ませて実行すると同じ結果になるようです (試してみるとよいでしょう)。つまり, requests で指定する UserAgent (も含め) 以外の何らかの違いで, サイトは動作を変えてるのかも

Comment: まずは requests でページを取得した時点の結果が同じなのか異なるのかを確認してみてください。

Comment: 教えていただきありがとうございます。
JupyterNotebookとGoogleColaboratoryで取得している、requestsで取得している、r.contentの内容が異なっています。requestsでのデータ取得の段階で、２つの環境で差異があるようです。